# Lenovo ThinkPad T580/P52s System Firmware Update

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, firmware

yesterday i got this firmware update notification in Ubuntu (18.04) software center.
Trying to confirm the update nothing happens. The text dissapear and about two seconds it comes back.
what am I doing wrong?

```
Lenovo ThinkPad T580/P52s System Firmware
CHANGES IN THIS RELEASE
Version 1.14
[Important updates]
 • Nothing.
[New functions or enhancements]
 • Support TPM firmware update by utility.
[Problem fixes]
 • Fix an issue where WLAN network might not be an expected speed.
 • Fix an issue where the system may sleep suddenly and randomly.
 • Fix an issue where the system may not unlock by TPM pin code.
```

Answer (score 1):

had same issue. You can run it manually using `fwupdmgr update`